# placeholder to textarea inside a JSP page

Tags: jsp, textarea, placeholder

I am trying to use the plcaeholder attribute inside a `<textarea>` tag of a jsp page.

```
<textarea rows="13" cols="94" id="message" name="txtAreaName" style="vertical-align: onclick="textAreaPlaceholding()">Enter the message here...</textarea>
```

But it shows that `placeholder="some_text_content"` is not a valid attribute(Undefined attribute name (placeholder)). What can be the problem? Am I using any wrong attribute inside the `<textarea>` tag or anything else like I follow a wrong syntax.

As it don't work, for now I displayed a text content which will go invisible when user clicks the textarea and/or when the textarea is edited; with the help of a javascript method which you can find in the above code as 'onclick="textAreaPlaceholding()"'. But I need to know the exact problem and solution.

Thanks in advance for your responses.!

Comment: What is the DOCTYPE of the html ?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<textarea placeholder="Enter the message here...">
</textarea>
```

Comment: @The New Idiot: It is,
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`.

Comment: ganesh, as I mentioned earlier, 'Undefined attribute name (placeholder)' is what I am getting when I add teh attribute 'placeholder' inside my `<textarea>` tag.

Comment: check this one is useful for you "data placeholder" http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/SkRN9/2/

Comment: ganesh, what I had done with my `'onclick="textAreaPlaceholding()"'` was that kinda thing only. i just want to know if there is a direct way to use the 'placeholder' attribute. thanks for your suggestion.